# List Set should be a sort, but it isn't

Tags: agda

I just start using Agda to work on some proof of concept.

In this case, I want a data type with similar structure as `Relation` defined below.

(for simplicity, the element of data type `A` and definition of function `relation-1` are omitted).

When `Relation` is defined like this:

```
open import Data.Product using (_×_)
open import Data.List using (List; _∷_; [])
open import Data.Unit using (⊤)

data A : Set where

relation-1 : A → List A
relation-1 = {!!} 

map-1 : ∀{A : Set} → (A → Set) → List A → List Set
map-1 _ [] = []
map-1 p (a ∷ as) = p a ∷ (map-1 p as) 

map-2 : ∀{A : Set} → (A → Set) → List A → Set
map-2 p [] = ⊤
map-2 p (a ∷ as) = p a × (map-2 p as)

data Relation : A → Set where 
  refl : (a : A) → Relation a
  expand : (a : A) → map-1 Relation (relation-1 a) → Relation a
```

The error message is :

```
List Set should be a sort, but it isn't
when checking that the inferred type of an application
  List Set
matches the expected type
  _43
```

However, after replacing map-1 with map-2

```
data Relation : A → Set where 
  refl : (a : A) → Relation a
  expand : (a : A) → map-2 Relation (relation-1 a) → Relation a
```

there will be no type error.

My question is why `List Set` is not a valid type when `map-1` is used in `Relation` ?

It works well in the definition of `map-1` and in other cases such as in the heterogeneous list:

```
data HList : (List Set) → Set where
  [] : HList []
  _∷_ : {A : Set}{xs : List Set} → A → HList xs → HList (A ∷ xs)
```

Comment: I know that `map-1 Relation (relation-1 a)` is an element of sort `List Set` and if `relation-1 a` gives `[a1, a2, a3]`,  `map-1 Relation (relation-1 a)` will gives `Relation a1 :: Relation a2 :: Relation a3 :: []`.  Similarly,  `map-2 Relation (relation-1 a)` gives `Relation a1 x (Relation a2 x Relation a3)`  and its an element of `Set`, but why the latter is acceptable here ?  Is it because it is hard to provide evidence for `Relation a1 :: Relation a2 :: Relation a3 :: []` since `::` is not a constructor of some type ?

Comment: `map-1 Relation (relation-1 a) : List Set`, so its value is a particular list of sets, let's say  the list `[A, B]` where `A` and `B` are some concrete `Set`s. So then your type for `expand` says that its second argument should be something that has the type `[A, B]`, but that doesn't mean anything...

Comment: (having deleted my incorrect answer) Note a subtle difference between `map-1` and `map-2`: `map-2` for an empty list produces type `T`, of which you can always construct a witness; but `map-1` in this universe is an empty list of types. Even if the latter meant a type, what would a value of an "empty list of types" be?

Comment: @SassaNF Yes, you are right.  '::' is a value constructor, thus elements of List Set consist of types of Set0, however, these elements are primitive constant and can only be used as index or in type level functions, such as in HList or map-1.  Whereas 'x' is a type constructor, the structure of its elements are well defined primitive constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want is just the `All` here :
https://plfa.github.io/Lists/#21511